# How to get data directly from the mic’s ADC?

Tags: objective-c, ios

Is there a way to get data from the microphone port’s  Analog-to-Digital-Converter directly? Or at least at a lower level then doing it by CoreAudio?

Answer (score 0):

There is not. CoreAudio is the lowest level available. You should be able to get a 6ms buffer back from the mic. Try doing that on Android.